# Uploading a file with REST to Sharepoint DMS

Tags: php, sharepoint

I can't find any example on uploading file to Sharepoint 2010 using REST services, we are trying to do this with php but example in any language not using some native sharepoint library would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone seeing this, after some searching, there isn't a way to do that, documented anyway. REST can be used for lists and other simple tasks, but this is not documented.
It seems that this will change in Sharepoint 2013 as it provides much larger REST implementation.